# Why is SQL doing an inner join where an outer join is needed

Tags: sql, join, merge

I have two tables which I want to "outer" join (and then fetch) using SQL. The exact SQL query (in question) is:

```
SELECT
    LEFT(a.cusip, 6) AS cusip6, 
    a.date, a.prc, a.ret, a.vol, a.spread, a.shrout,
    b.epsf12, (b.seqq-b.pstkq) / b.cshoq AS bps
FROM
    crsp.msf a 
FULL JOIN 
    compa.fundq b ON (LEFT(a.cusip, 6) = LEFT(b.cusip, 6) 
                  AND a.date = b.datadate)
WHERE 
    (b.datadate BETWEEN '2010-01-01' and '2015-12-31') 
    AND (a.date BETWEEN '2010-01-01' and '2015-12-31') 
    AND (b.cshoq > 0)
```

This returns 670'293 rows.

But when I fetch the two datasets separately and (outer) join them through R-merge(), I get 1'182'093 rows. The two separate queries I use are:

```
SELECT  
    LEFT(cusip, 6) AS cusip6, date, prc, ret, vol, spread, shrout 
FROM
    crsp.msf 
WHERE 
    date BETWEEN '2010-01-01' and '2015-12-31'

SELECT 
    LEFT(cusip, 6) AS cusip6, datadate AS date, epsf12, 
    (seqq-pstkq)/cshoq AS bps 
FROM
    compa.fundq 
WHERE 
    datadate BETWEEN '2010-01-01' and '2015-12-31' 
    AND cshoq > 0
```

And then I merge (outer join) using:

```
merge(x = data_1, y = data_2, by.x = c("cusip6", "date"), by.y = c("cusip6", "date"), all = T)
```

This returns 1'182'093 rows which is correct. So my original (first) SQL query is in fact performing an "inner join" when I explicitly specify an outer join. The below R-merge() returned 670'293 rows re-validating that the fetched data from SQL is indeed an inner join.

```
merge(x = data_1, y = data_2, by.x = c("cusip6", "date"), by.y = c("cusip6", "date"))
```

What am I doing wrong with my SQL query?

Comment: Which RDBMS is this for? Please add a tag to specify whether you're using `mysql`, `postgresql`, `sql-server`, `oracle` or `db2` - or something else entirely.

Comment: How would columns from `a` be filled when there are no matching rows? And how would this work with a `where` clause that has an explicit clause for some columns from `a` ?

Answer (score 1):

Because the WHERE clause is applied after the JOINs. At this point there are NULL values *(as a result of 'failed' JOINs)*, and those rows fail the WHERE clause.

If you want an OUTER JOIN and a filter, put the filter in the JOIN or a sub-query.

```
SELECT
    LEFT(a.cusip, 6) AS cusip6, 
    a.date, a.prc, a.ret, a.vol, a.spread, a.shrout,
    b.epsf12, (b.seqq-b.pstkq) / b.cshoq AS bps
FROM
    (SELECT * FROM crsp.msf WHERE date BETWEEN '2010-01-01' and '2015-12-31') a
FULL JOIN 
    (SELECT * FROM compa.fundq WHERE datadate BETWEEN '2010-01-01' and '2015-12-31' AND cshoq > 0) b
        ON  LEFT(a.cusip, 6) = LEFT(b.cusip, 6) 
        AND a.date = b.datadate
```